# How to decide hypothesis function for NN having non-linear training set?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, scientific-computing

We have 4 numeric inputs which are non-linearly related to each other. Our objective is to predict the output by using backward propagation model. The scenario we are imaging is as follows ,
[image]

As per our knowledge( we don't have thorough understanding), we are considering the equation for calculating output(Y) for any neuron is,

```
        Y  =  w1 * X1  + w2 * X2 + w3 * X3 + w4  * X4 ?
```

where,
          Y is output
          X is input ( X1,X2,X3,X4)
          w is weight

So in output layer if output(Y) is different than expected one, we will modify the weight using error correction.

Is it necessary to have specific output function(hypothesis function) for non-linear data sets? or Above function can be used?

Answer (score 2):

It is a good way to think in math, but I can't agree with the equation you listed above.

For hidden neuron 1 (HN1), its input (inputHN1) is
`w11*X1 + w21*X2 + w31*X3 + w41*X4`; and the output is
`f(inputHN1)`. Note that `f()` could be an nonlinear function (can be linear as well).

Simply for HN2, we have `f(inputHN2)`

`Y = beta1*f(inputHN1) + beta2*f(inputHN2)`

MLP's weights (w and beta) will be trained by back-propagation.

You would see that if `f()` is nonlinear, it is perfectly to model an nonlinear function.

Of course if `f()` is linear, it can only give good approximation for linear functions.

Well, the hypothesis is always good to help, if you have prior knowledge on what you are trying to model. For example, instead of first order, you can have second order such as X1X2, X1^2, etc.

Comment: Yes, your equation is right, I should number all those neurons, So this means in backward propagation, the next neuron's output is always summation of weights*node(neuron values) of previous neurons) ? thanks for the reply Robin

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is why the training of MLP like above consists of feed-forward and back-propagation, literally.